# How to pass multiple parameter to @Directives (@Components) in Angular with TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Since I've created `@Directive` as `SelectableDirective`, I'm little bit confused, about how to pass **more than one** value to the custom directive. I have searched a lot but didn't get proper solution in *Angular* with *Typescript*.

Here is what my sample code is:

Parent Component as `MCQComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Question } from '../question/question';
import { AppService } from '../app.service/app.service';
import { SelectableDirective } from '../selectable.directive/selectable.directive';
import { ResultComponent } from '../result-component/result.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'mcq-component',
    template: "
         .....
        <div *ngIf = 'isQuestionView'>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor = 'let opt of currentQuestion.options' 
                    [selectable] = 'opt'
                    (selectedOption) = 'onOptionSelection($event)'>
                    {{opt.option}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            .....
        </div>

    "
    providers: [AppService],
    directives: [SelectableDirective, ResultComponent]
})
export class MCQComponent implements OnInit{
    private currentIndex:any = 0;
    private currentQuestion:Question = new Question();
    private questionList:Array<Question> = [];
    ....
    constructor(private appService: AppService){}
    ....
}
```

This is a parent component having custom directive **[selectable]** which takes one param called **opt**.

Here is the code for this directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import { Question } from '../question/question';

@Directive({
    selector: '[selectable]'
})
export class SelectableDirective{
    private el: HTMLElement;
    @Input('selectable') option:any;

    ...
}
```

So here I want to pass **more parameters from parent** component, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

From the [**Documentation**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html)

> As with components, you can add as many directive property bindings as
>   you need by stringing them along in the template.
>
> Add an input property to `HighlightDirective` called `defaultColor`:
>
> ```
> @Input() defaultColor: string;
> ```

Markup

> ```
> <p [myHighlight]="color" defaultColor="violet">
>   Highlight me too!
> </p>
> ```
>
> **Angular** knows that the `defaultColor` binding belongs to the `HighlightDirective` because you made it public with the `@Input`
>   decorator.
>
> Either way, the `@Input` decorator tells Angular that this property is
>   public and available for binding by a parent component. Without
>   `@Input`, Angular refuses to bind to the property.

**For your example**

**With many parameters**

Add properties into the `Directive` class with `@Input()` decorator

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[selectable]'
})
export class SelectableDirective{
    private el: HTMLElement;

    @Input('selectable') option:any;   
    @Input('first') f;
    @Input('second') s;

    ...
}
```

And in the template pass bound properties to your `li` element

```
<li *ngFor = 'let opt of currentQuestion.options' 
    [selectable] = 'opt' 
    [first]='YourParameterHere'
    [second]='YourParameterHere'
    (selectedOption) = 'onOptionSelection($event)'>
    {{opt.option}}
</li>
```

Here on the `li` element we have a directive with name `selectable`. In the `selectable` we have two `@Input()`'s, `f` with name `first` and `s` with name `second`. We have applied these two on the `li` properties with name `[first]` and `[second]`. And our directive will find these properties on that `li` element, which are set for him with `@Input()` decorator. So `selectable`, `[first]` and `[second]` will be bound to every directive on `li`, which has property with these names.

**With single parameter**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[selectable]'
})
export class SelectableDirective{
    private el: HTMLElement;

    @Input('selectable') option:any;   
    @Input('params') params;

    ...
}
```

Markup

```
<li *ngFor = 'let opt of currentQuestion.options' 
    [selectable] = 'opt' 
    [params]='{firstParam: 1, seconParam: 2, thirdParam: 3}'
    (selectedOption) = 'onOptionSelection($event)'>
    {{opt.option}}
</li>
```

Comment: But what should I write in parent component?

Comment: @Shree see the edited anwser. In the `li` you pass a parameter in the same way

Comment: But what if I have multiple attr directives?

Comment: you will give the parameter for which it is with the @Input decorator

Comment: thanks a lot, I really appreciate your reply, now I got it.

Comment: shouldn't it be [defaultColor]="violet" instead of defaultColor="violet" ?

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs when you use `[defaultColor]="violet"`, it tries to execute the right part and find a property with name violet, without `[]` brackets it uses the right part as string

Comment: What happens if multiple directives accept inputs with the same name?Seems like this would cause an unresolvable conflict for the developer. Is it considered best practice to do this? It seems like it may be a better practice to pass an object to the directive containing properties representing any additional arguments.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan 1) shouldn't `[defaultColor]="violet"` be like `[defaultColor]="'violet'"`, value wrapped in `'`. If not using `'`, should be like `defaultColor="violet"` 2) If a property name is the same as the selector then we can pass the value as `[selectable] = 'opt'`. Now for other property/ies, need one or more properties or use param as you have used. Can't we pass multiple parameters as `opt` rather than using additional properties or use params as you have? 3) so do i then access params in the directive as `params.firstParam` and shouldn't params be of type `any` in this case?

Comment: this example simply not working for me: `appHighlight [highlightColor]="'orange'"`

Comment: In case you need to pass an object to embedded component.

   <tr app-team *ngFor="let team of uniqueTeams" [team]="team"></tr>

Answer (score 21):

to pass many options you can pass a object to a @Input decorator with custom data in a single line.

In the template

```
<li *ngFor = 'let opt of currentQuestion.options' 
                [selectable] = 'opt'
                [myOptions] ="{first: opt.val1, second: opt.val2}" // these are your multiple parameters
                (selectedOption) = 'onOptionSelection($event)' >
     {{opt.option}}
</li>
```

so in Directive class

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[selectable]'
})

export class SelectableDirective{
  private el: HTMLElement;
  @Input('selectable') option:any;
  @Input('myOptions') data;

  //do something with data.first
  ...
  // do something with data.second
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. That way I can get away with only one directive binding pr. html element. Thanks a bunch @Dag !

Comment: @MartinJH It's worth mentioning this solution does not work well when using the change detection strategy `OnPush`. If you want to use that strategy, it's better to avoid using objects as @Input().

Comment: @enf0rcer You can of course still use this method with OnPush, you just need to push a new object to the directive. So, embedding the object literal in the template is a no-go - you'd need to push it through an observable on the component.

Answer (score 14):

Another neat option is to use the `Directive` as an element and not as an attribute.

```
@Directive({
   selector: 'app-directive'
})
export class InformativeDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input()
    public first: string;

    @Input()
    public second: string;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       console.log(`Values: ${this.first}, ${this.second}`);
    }
}
```

And this directive can be used like that:

```
<app-someKindOfComponent>
    <app-directive [first]="'first 1'" [second]="'second 1'">A</app-directive>
    <app-directive [first]="'First 2'" [second]="'second 2'">B</app-directive>
    <app-directive [first]="'First 3'" [second]="'second 3'">C</app-directive>
</app-someKindOfComponent>`
```

Simple, neat and powerful.

Comment: Thanks, that's also a simplest way.

Comment: I didn't realize directives could be used as elements. Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the above solutions I used `@Input()` in a directive and able to pass multiple arrays of values in the directive.

```
selector: '[selectorHere]',

@Input() options: any = {};
```

Input.html

```
<input selectorHere [options]="selectorArray" />
```

Array from TS file

```
selectorArray= {
  align: 'left',
  prefix: '$',
  thousands: ',',
  decimal: '.',
  precision: 2
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i put my answer too, which may be incomplete, and also has been seen on stackoverflow from an other post where i come with this solution which seems more accurate as the parameters are stick with the directive :
(Please read the comments, it's just a sample, not the complete code), you should be able to use it as this :

```
 <div *e777HasRole="['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']; op: 'OR'; op2 :'foo';">
    <p>foo</p>
 </div>
```

.

```
    ...
@Directive({
  selector: '[e777HasRole]',
})
//check des permissions de l'utilisateur loggé

// s'utilise comme ceci :         
//*e777HasRole="['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']"
//*e777HasRole="['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']; op: 'OR';"
//*e777HasRole="['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADMIN']; op: 'AND';"
//*e777HasRole="['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADMIN']; op: 'NOR';"

//ATENTION, en cours de dev sur les opérateurs, ne surtout pas utiliser tel quel !!!!
//c'est juste pour montrer le principe des paramètres sur une directive


export class E777HasRoleDirective implements OnInit {
  private loggedInUser$: Observable<User | undefined>;
  private currentLoggedInUser: User | undefined;

  private roles: string[];


  private logicalOp = 'AND';

  private isHidden = true;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    //private userService: UserService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
  ) {
    this.loggedInUser$ = this.authenticationService.loggedInUser$;
    this.currentLoggedInUser = undefined;
    this.roles = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInUser$.subscribe((user) => {
      this.currentLoggedInUser = user;
      this.updateView();
    });
  }

  @Input()
  set e777HasRole(val: string[]) {
    this.roles = val;
    this.updateView();
  }


  //THIS is the important part : notice this : "e777HasRoleOp" = "e777HasRole" (name of the directive selector) + "Op" (name of the parameter)
  @Input()
  set e777HasRoleOp(permop: string) {
    this.logicalOp = permop;
    console.log('opoerateur est : ' + permop);
    this.updateView();
  }


  //you could get a second parameter "op2" like this
  //@Input()
  //set e777HasRoleOp2(pop2: string) {
  //...
  //this.paramop2 = pop2
  //...
  //  this.updateView();
  //}
  //you should be able to use it as this
//*e777HasRole="['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']; op: 'OR'; op2 :'foo';"
...

  private checkPermission(): boolean {
    if (this.logicalOp.toUpperCase() === 'OR') {
      return this.checkPermission_or();
    } else if (this.logicalOp.toUpperCase() === 'AND') {
      return this.checkPermission_and();
    } else if (this.logicalOp.toUpperCase() === 'NOR') {
      return this.checkPermission_nor();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  ...
}
```