# How to pass optional parameter to @Directives in Angular 2 with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

[This is how you insert params into a directive.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843532/how-to-pass-multiple-parameter-to-directives-in-angular-2-with-typescript)

```
<p [gridGroup]="gridGroup"></p>
```

But what I am wanting to do is make the param optional so that I won't have to always include it within my class.

I am required to insert gridGroup in each class that references this html source.

I have tried

```
<p [gridGroup?]="gridGroup"></p>
```

and

```
<p [gridGroup]="gridGroup?"></p>
```

Both give me compile errors

Answer (score 0):

In your component intialize the gridGroup property to a value, that way if the property is not declared in the parent component it still has a value/won't cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
@Input set gridGroup(value: any) {
      this._gridGroup= value;
      doSomething(value);
    }
```