# Is it possible to create a dynamic directive selector (like [class.active])?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I want to create a directive with a semi-dynamic selector.

Angular team use this approach in some places, for example `[style.width.px]="100"` and `(keyup.enter)="doSomething()"`.

There is a way to do this in my custom directive? Something like `[my-directive.some-data]="variable"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `@Input()` to your directive, though the syntax is slightly different from what you wrote.

so you could do something like

```
<p myDirective [someData]="variable">lorem ipsum</p>
```

Check out [the angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property) for more information

EDIT:
If you want to see an example with multiple inputs, check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38843554/14492841)

Answer (score 0):

After publish the answer, I think that really it's not what are you looking for, but....you can create a directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mydirective.one],[mydirective.two],[mydirective.three]'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('mydirective.one') prop1
  @Input('mydirective.two') prop2
  @Input('mydirective.three') prop3

  constructor(private el:ElementRef,private renderer:Renderer2) {}
   ngOnInit()
   {
    console.log(this.prop1,this.prop2,this.prop3)
    if (this.prop1)
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement,"background-color",prop1)

    if (this.prop2)
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement,"color",prop2)

    if (this.prop3)
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement,"font-size",prop3)

   }
}
```

See how the selectors can be sepatated by commas, and you need use the way `@Input(name.prop) variable` because you can not use a variable separated by dot

**Update** perfahs you are looking for host. You can declare a directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mydirective]',
  host:{'[class.active]':'value'}
})
export class MyDirective {
  value:boolean=false;
  @Input() set mydirective(value)
  {
      this.value=value;
  }
```